# How to keep a program running with a scanf

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, scanf, interruption

I want to find a way to exit from the "loop in question" (see below) with keeping the program running, I mean : In the program there must be the message: "preparing to send informations, exit to stop !" if the user doesn't type exit, the program must still running without waiting the user to click in a character and then enter. The informations must be sent continuously until the user type exit to quit the program.

I hope I explain well the problem, and I'm sure that there is an easy solution

Thank you in advance for your help

```
do
{

    /* menu */
    printf("\r\n");
    printf("1 : Start, Sending Informations.\r\n");
    printf("2 : Quit.\r\n");
    printf("choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &nChoice);

    printf("\n Trying to do a connection \n \r");

    /* if connection is not established, call accept, TCP SERVER */
    if (fd_client == -1)
    { 
        printf("ready to accept...\n");             
        fd_client = accept(fd_listen, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

        if (fd_client >= 0) 
        {
            printf("accept: %s, port %d\r\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), htons(client_addr.sin_port));
        }
    }

    if (fd_client < 0) 
    {
        printf(" connection is not established, continue to accept\n");

        /*connection is not established, continue to accept*/
        continue;               
    }

    FD_ZERO(&rfd);
    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
    FD_ZERO(&efd);
    FD_SET(fd_tty, &rfd);
    FD_SET(fd_client, &rfd);
    maxfd = (fd_tty > fd_client ? fd_tty : fd_client) + 1;

    /*connection is established, call select to see if any data arrived from the GPS*/
    printf("connection is established, seeing if any data arrived\n");

    char chaine1[256];
    char chaine2[] = "exit";
    int i;

    if (nChoice == 1)
    {  
        do // THE LOOP IN QUESTION
        { 
            printf("preparing to send informations, exit to stop !\n");
            i = strcmp(chaine1, chaine2); // Building the condition to exit
            scanf("%s", chaine1);
            fflush(stdin);
            // printf ("i= %d\n",i); 

            ret = select(maxfd, &rfd, &wfd, &efd, &tm);

            if (ret < 0) // Select failed 
            { 
                printf("select fail\r\n");
                break;
            } 
            else if (ret == 0) 
            {
                continue;   /*no data arrived, continue to call select*/
            }
            else 
                printf("data is arriving \n");

            if (FD_ISSET(fd_tty, &rfd)) /*tty port has data to be read*/
            {
                ret = read(fd_tty, buf, sizeof(buf));

                if (ret <= 0) 
                {
                    printf("read tty port fail\r\n");
                    break;
                }

                if (send(fd_client, buf, ret, 0) < 0) /*send data to ethernet*/
                {   
                    printf("send to ethernet fail\r\n");
                    break;              
                }
            }

            if (FD_ISSET(fd_client, &rfd)) /*tcp client has data to be read*/
            { 
                ret = recv(fd_client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

                if (ret < 0) 
                {
                    printf("read from ethernet fail\r\n");
                    break;
                } 
                else if (ret == 0) 
                {
                    printf("disconnect by remote\r\n");
                    close(fd_client);
                    fd_client = -1;
                    continue; /*continue to accept...*/
                }

                if (write(fd_tty, buf, ret) < 0) /*send data to tty port*/
                {       
                    printf("write to tty fail\r\n");
                    break;              
                }
            }

        } while (i != 0 ); // The exit condition
    }
} while(nChoice != 2);
```

Comment: Please fix your incomplete title.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of the code, but gave up. *PLEASE* make this into a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: you should first `scanf("%s", chaine1);` and then `i = strcmp(chaine1, chaine2);`. The other way you will have an uninitialized `chaince1` buffer the first time

Comment: **Warning**: Using `scanf()` string conversions (`%s` or `%[]`) without a field width (or assignment suppression with `*`) is **dangerous**, because user-supplied input can overflow your buffer.  Not only that, but you completely fail to use its return value, leading to erroneous operation whenever you get unexpected inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple thing you can do is to wait for a timeout. But with `scanf` you can't do that so you can go for a `select()` call for the event at `stdin` and proceed if no event within that time.

Please check the following link 
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/96544-unblock-scanf-call.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be noted that `fflush();` is designed for output streams and is undefined when used on input streams, 1 way to get around the problem would be `scanf(" %s", chaine1);` or create a function to clear input buffer.